# iPad - Dismiss keyboard for modal view controller in UIModalPresentationFormSheet mode

Tags: ipad, keyboard, modal-dialog, dismiss, uimodalpresentationstyle

In my iPad app I want to present some view controllers in **UIModalPresentationFormSheet** modal mode **without keyboard**.

I use it to display help as an example.

At the moment I use the code found on the one of stackoverflow answers to dismiss it:

```
// trick to dismiss keyboard in iPad:    
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        // iPad specific behaviour:

        @try
        {
            Class UIKeyboardImpl = NSClassFromString(@"UIKeyboardImpl");
            id activeInstance = [UIKeyboardImpl performSelector:@selector(activeInstance)];
            [activeInstance performSelector:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            //NSLog(@"%@", exception);
        }

    }
```

But I am afraid Apple can reject it in during approval process as it uses private API

I can see **Apple developers achieved that in the GarageBand help screens** so it must be the 'proper' way to do this.

Would appreciate help as our client do not want to change design concept because of such a slight limitation.

**UPDATE:
Just today I was rejected from AppStore:**

> We found that your app uses one or
>   more non-public APIs, which is not in
>   compliance with the App Store Review
>   Guidelines. The use of non-public APIs
>   is not permissible because it can lead
>   to a poor user experience should these
>   APIs change.
>
> We found the following non-public APIs
>   in your app:
>
> **activeInstance dismissKeyboard**

So please **do NOT follow this advice**:
[How to HIDE the iPad keyboard from a MODAL view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762251/how-to-hide-the-ipad-keyboard-from-a-modal-view-controller/3603945#3603945)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment in the mentioned question: **you can construct the selector dynamically with NSSelectorFromString()**. This will be accepted for the AppStore, your bug will be fixed and your code will not crash.

Comment: This would be to easy to cheat Apple. I am sure they are able to scan selectors constructed from NSString also. They would not allow to bypass private restrictions so easily.